# Getting an error about a label name or textbox id not being in context

Tags: asp.net

I am getting a number of errors such as

> The name 'lblThankYou' does not exist in the current context

However the asp.net code has the 'lblThankYou' as a label name

```
<asp:Label ID="lblThankYou" runat="server" Visible="False" Font-Bold  Font-Size ="Medium" ><table><tr><td>Thank you for submitting your request.  We will respond the following business day.  
                        For immediate assistance, please call us at 1-800-xxx-xxxx.</tr></table></asp:Label>
```

However when I try to preview the file in the browser I get this

> Parser Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   type
>   'xxxxxxxxxxxxSolution2010.Signup3'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Title=""
>   Language="C#"
>   MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageLicensing.master"
>   AutoEventWireup="true"
>   CodeBehind="Signup3.aspx.cs"
>   Inherits="xxxxxxxxxxxSolution2010.Signup3"
>   %> Line 2:   Line 3:
>
> Source File: /Signup3.aspx    Line: 1

The odd thing is the code is there in the page and I tried rebuilding it to fix it but to no avail

I am using ASP.net 4.0 and visual studio 2010 if that helps

Comment: what happens if you run the web application normally (with F5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the way I fixed it was by creating a new code file and copying the existing code on to it and saving it with the same old file name.

That fixed the issue

Comment: Do you have a theory as to what was causing the error?

Comment: This.josh ,I dont really have a theory about it sorry .I thought it was something to do with the way the visual studio handles rebuilds but I couldnt find any documentation on the internet which supports it.However its a workaround which seems to fix the issue just in case someone is breaking their heads over it

Answer (score 0):

Your table cell is missing a closing tag

Comment: sorry thats not the case since i just copied part of the code

Comment: You have an open <TD> tag, and the next closing tag is a </TR> tag.  <tr><td>...</tr>    See your code snippet above. The code that you pasted into your questions can and should cause errors.